# chatbot error : Not getting Chatbot answers from training csv file

Tags: python, csv, chatbot

I am trying to make a simple rule-based chatbot to deal repeated FAQs. I have saved questions and answers in a csv file and trying to train the model for the csv data.
Code is :

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

bot = ChatBot(
    "Chat Bot",
    storage_adapter="chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter",
    database="Bot1.sqlite3"
)
trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(bot)
trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.english")
```

It is being run successfully and I see one trainingdata.yml is getting created. But, one yml is getting created inside the folder where my csv is stored and one yml is getting created outside of that folder.
When I run the app,chatbot does not show the answer which I gave in csv instead it gives Dummy answers.

I tried updating the code as below :

```
trainer.train('/data/trainingdata.yml')
```

But it gives error :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/trainingdata.yml'
```

however it creates the yml file in the folder.

But chatbot still gives dummy response.

Can someone help on it ?

Comment: maybe file is in different folder ? Or maybe it should be without staring `/` like `'data/trainingdata.yml'` ?

Answer (score 0):

It got resolved after removing first / from path . also removed sqllite file everytime when updating training data. Now, the issue is resolved and its answering as per the data in CSV file.